# Why doesn't my toggle switch doesn't change states on click?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a "Before and After" toggle that is working correctly in regards to toggling the before and after image when the toggle is switched on. However, for some reason the toggle isn't changing states (gray to blue and moving from the left to the right).

I'm looking all over the place here, but I can't tell why it's not visibly toggling. If you have any thoughts, I would really appreciate the second pair of eyes.

Thanks in advance if you can solve my conundrum!

```js
// BEFORE AND AFTER TOGGLE
jQuery(function($){
    $('#cflow_flag').on("change", function() {
      $('#submit-job').toggle();
      $('#submit-cflow').toggle();
    });
  });
```

```css
/* ROUNDED TOGGLE SWITCH */
/* The switch - the box around the slider */
.switch {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 60px;
  height: 34px;
}

/* Hide default HTML checkbox */
.switch input {
  opacity: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
}

/* The slider */
.slider {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #ccc;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

.slider:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: 26px;
  width: 26px;
  left: 4px;
  bottom: 4px;
  background-color: white;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

input:checked + .slider {
  background-color: #2196F3;
}

input:focus + .slider {
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px #2196F3;
}

input:checked + .slider:before {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(26px);
  -ms-transform: translateX(26px);
  transform: translateX(26px);
}

/* Rounded sliders */
.slider.round {
  border-radius: 34px;
}

.slider.round:before {
  border-radius: 50%;
}

/* TOGGLE ITEMS */
.before-after-wrap {
 text-align: center;
}
.toggle-wrapper {
 display: flex;
 justify-content: space-between;
 width: 40%;
 margin: 0 auto;
}
.toggle-title {
 margin-bottom: 25px;
}

#submit-cflow {
  display: none; 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="before-after-wrap">
 <div class="toggle-title">CLICK TO SWITCH TO SEE THE BEFORE</div>
 
 <div class="toggle-wrapper">
  <div class="bs">B.S.</div>
  <div>
   <label class="switch">
     <input type="checkbox" id="cflow_flag"><br>
     <span class="slider round"></span>
   </label>
  </div>
  <div class="as">A.S.</div>
 </div>
 
 <div type="button" id="submit-job"  class="btn btn-primary">
   <img src="https://stable.stable-demos.com/wp-content/uploads/slide-before-2.jpg" alt="" />
 </div>
 <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="commit-view">
    <div type="button" id="submit-cflow" class="btn btn-primary">
      <img src="https://stable.stable-demos.com/wp-content/uploads/slide-after-2.jpg" alt="" />
    </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because in the CSS you are using the `+` selector to select the direct sibling of the input. But you have a `<br>` tag.

```
<input type="checkbox" id="cflow_flag"><br><span class="slider round"></span>
```

You can fix that by using the `~` selector. Or you can keep your CSS the same and simply remove the `<br>` tag:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="cflow_flag"><span class="slider round"></span>
```

Here's the important part for the CSS:

```
input:checked ~.slider {
  background-color: #2196F3;
}

input:focus ~ .slider {
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px #2196F3;
}

input:checked ~ .slider:before {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(26px);
  -ms-transform: translateX(26px);
  transform: translateX(26px);
}
```

```js
// BEFORE AND AFTER TOGGLE
jQuery(function($) {
  $('#cflow_flag').on("change", function() {
    $('#submit-job').toggle();
    $('#submit-cflow').toggle();
  });
});
```

```css
/* ROUNDED TOGGLE SWITCH */


/* The switch - the box around the slider */

.switch {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 60px;
  height: 34px;
}


/* Hide default HTML checkbox */

.switch input {
  opacity: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
}


/* The slider */

.slider {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #ccc;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

.slider:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: 26px;
  width: 26px;
  left: 4px;
  bottom: 4px;
  background-color: white;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

input:checked~.slider {
  background-color: #2196F3;
}

input:focus~.slider {
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px #2196F3;
}

input:checked~.slider:before {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(26px);
  -ms-transform: translateX(26px);
  transform: translateX(26px);
}


/* Rounded sliders */

.slider.round {
  border-radius: 34px;
}

.slider.round:before {
  border-radius: 50%;
}


/* TOGGLE ITEMS */

.before-after-wrap {
  text-align: center;
}

.toggle-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 40%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.toggle-title {
  margin-bottom: 25px;
}

#submit-cflow {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="before-after-wrap">
  <div class="toggle-title">CLICK TO SWITCH TO SEE THE BEFORE</div>

  <div class="toggle-wrapper">
    <div class="bs">B.S.</div>
    <div>
      <label class="switch">
     <input type="checkbox" id="cflow_flag"><br>
     <span class="slider round"></span>
   </label>
    </div>
    <div class="as">A.S.</div>
  </div>

  <div type="button" id="submit-job" class="btn btn-primary">
    <img src="https://stable.stable-demos.com/wp-content/uploads/slide-before-2.jpg" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="commit-view">
    <div type="button" id="submit-cflow" class="btn btn-primary">
      <img src="https://stable.stable-demos.com/wp-content/uploads/slide-after-2.jpg" alt="" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I have never used the ~ selector before. THANK YOU! This was exactly the problem.

Comment: Right on! The `~` selector is for any sibling of the element. Check out https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Introduction_to_CSS/Combinators_and_multiple_selectors for more information on selectors.